# Django email activation via Outlook not working, Microsoft clicks on activation link

Tags: django, email, activation

Using Django activation token via e-mail, sent by existing SMTP server...
Does anybody have a clue why this may go wrong using MS Outlook (even when I copy paste the link) while it works fine when I have the activation link sent to my Gmail... In the code below, I get the "Account activation failed..." response instead of being logged in when the link was sent to an Outlook account. The user is created and activated in both cases though...

in views.py:

```
def activate(request, uidb64, token):
    try:
        uid = force_text(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
        user = User.objects.get(pk=uid)
    except (TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, User.DoesNotExist):
        user = None

    if user is not None and account_activation_token.check_token(user, token):
        user.is_active = True
        user.profile.email_confirmed = True
        user.save()
        login(request, user)
        return redirect('/')
    else:
        return render(request, 'account_activation_invalid.html')
```

When using Gmail I get redirected like you would expect...

Comment: can you post exact Traceback ?

Comment: Well, I can tell you this: Way before I even receive the activation email in the Outlook inbox, it has been used by somebody else... I can see this in my syslog before I even have seen the email: Mar 27 21:12:20 ascotserver uwsgi[1672]: [pid: 1691|app: 0|req: 8/78] 207.46.13.9 () {42 vars in 659 bytes} [Wed Mar 27 21:12:20 2019] GET /activate/Ng/54z-0fd98ea03be0b53ab7c4/ => generated 29 bytes in 14 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 3 headers in 108 bytes (2 switches on core 0)

Comment: And that IP belongs to Microsoft, I can even see them surfing a bit after using the token :S:S